# Why Google Nexus 7 is 7.3" in Eclipse, whereas it is 7" actually?

Tags: android, eclipse, android-emulator

I have an android application for mobile. I have to create an UI for Google Nexus 7. Before starting I want to make sure I am going in right direction. I am new to android and this is my first project for android. So I don't know what to do. Should I use Nexus 7 even though it is shown 7.3" in eclipse or use other one with 7" screen size?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because of the software buttons.

[image: Image of the Back arrow, Home, and Recent buttons]

Use the 7.3" emulator. If you select 7", the usable area of your screen without the software buttons will end up being 6.7"

Comment: Thank you. Can you tell me which dpi level should I use for developing UI for Nexus 7? I know this question is not a part of my original question, but if you can.

Comment: This is a tricky question. Nexus 7 is tvdpi, tvdpi roughly maps to hdpi, but the Nexus 7 will scale down your hdpi assets (except for the launcher icons which will probably be one scale above hdpi, therefore probably xhdpi). See this post: http://blog.blundell-apps.com/list-of-android-devices-with-pixel-density-buckets/ and see Dianne Hackborn's Google+ post: https://plus.google.com/105051985738280261832/posts/6eWwQvFGLV8